# Filter N level nested array of objects based upon multiple properties

Tags: javascript, angular, lodash

```
data = [
    {
      name: "Parent Level 1",
      questions: [
        {
          name: "question 1"
        }
      ],
      children: [
        {
          name: "Child 1 - P1",
          questions: [
            {
              name: "ability to code"
            },
            {
              name: "ability to do something"
            }
          ],
          children: [
            {
              name: "Child -2 P1",
              questions: [
                {
                  name: "figure out"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name : 'Parent Level 2',
      questions : [
        {name : 'question 1 P-2'}
      ]
    },
    {
      name : 'Parent Level 3',
      children: [
        {
          name : 'Child Level -1 P-3',
          children: [
          {
             name : 'Child Level 2- P-3',
             questions : [
              {
       name : 'Question level 2
              }
             ]
           }
          ]
          questions: [
            {name : 'hello there'}
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

**Problem:**

I need to perform a keyword search on the question, and if a question is found at a node - 3 let’s say then we need to return that node and all the parent nodes of that object.

For example, if I search for 'hello there', the final tree should be:

```
[
    {
      name : 'Parent Level 3',
      children: [
        {
          name : 'Child Level -1 P-3',
          children: [
          {
             name : 'Child Level 2- P-3',
             questions : []
           }
          ]
          questions: [
            {name : 'hello there'}
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

We can have children or questions [] at any node.

I am able to find the questions matching the search string, but I am not able to remove the unwanted nodes from the tree. Here is the code for that:

```
searchNode (data) {
    for (let d of data) {
      this.search(d)
    }
 }

 search(data) {
    let search = 'ability'
    if(!!data.questions && data.questions.length > 0) {
      data.questions = data.questions.filter((question) => {
        return question.name.includes(search)
      })
    }
    if(data.children && data.children.length > 0) {
      searchNode(data.children)
    }
  }

search(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. The demo code is in stackblitz. Check the result in the console.

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/arun205-recursive-call?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```
searchString = 'hello';
filteredData = [];

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.filteredData = [];
    this.data.forEach(node => {
        if (this.checkQtn(node)) {
            this.filteredData.push(node);
        }
    });
    console.log(this.filteredData);
}

checkQtn(node): Boolean {
    let response: Boolean = false;
    if (node.questions) {
        let qtns = [];
        qtns = node.questions;
        qtns.forEach(el => {
            const eachQtn: string = el.name;
            if (eachQtn.includes(this.searchString)) {
                response = true;
            }
        });
    }
    if (!response && node.children) {
        for (let i = 0; i < node.children.length && !response; i++) {
            response = this.checkQtn(node.children[i]);
        }
    }
    return response;
}
```

Comment: This does not filter the children array, For example if I search for "question 1" in the sample above it should return only the first node without the children array.

Comment: In the example that you gave in the question, the expected output node has parent and children. Only if you draft questions correctly, we can help you. If you update the question with expected output, I can help you.